# Get subscription id from invoice.payment_failed webhook in Stripe incorrect Hierarchy

Tags: php, stripe-payments

What is the hierarchy here?

It looks like it goes

$event->data->object->lines->data->subscription

I've tried that though, and Im not getting an ID. It's actually pretty confusing.

Here is the response, and why I am assuming the hierarchy is

`$event->data->object->lines->data->subscription`

I figured if I used say

$subID = $event->data->object->lines->data->subscription;

then

$subID should = "sub_randcomSUB"

`{
  "object": {
    "id": "in_randomnumbers",
    "object": "invoice",
    "amount_due": 20000,
    "amount_paid": 0,
    "amount_remaining": 20000,
    "application_fee": null,
    "attempt_count": 1,
    "attempted": true,
    "auto_advance": true,
    "billing": "charge_automatically",
    "billing_reason": "manual",
    "charge": "ch_randomnumbers",
    "closed": false,
    "currency": "usd",
    "customer": "cus_randomnumbers",
    "date": 1532039357,
    "description": null,
    "discount": null,
    "due_date": null,
    "ending_balance": 0,
    "forgiven": false,
    "hosted_invoice_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/invst_randomnumbers",
    "invoice_pdf": "https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/invst_randomcnumbers/pdf",
    "lines": {
      "object": "list",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "ii_randomnumbn",
          "object": "line_item",
          "amount": 20000,
          "currency": "usd",
          "description": "SSS",
          "discountable": true,
          "invoice_item": "ii_random",
          "livemode": false,
          "metadata": {
          },
          "period": {
            "end": 1532039351,
            "start": 1532039351
          },
          "plan": null,
          "proration": false,
          "quantity": 1,
          "subscription": "sub_randcomSUB",
          "type": "invoiceitem"
        }
      ],
      "has_more": false,
      "total_count": 1,
      "url": "/v1/invoices/in_randcom/lines"
    },
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "next_payment_attempt": 1532298568,
    "number": "5186095-0004",
    "paid": false,
    "period_end": 1534715394,
    "period_start": 1532036994,
    "receipt_number": null,
    "starting_balance": 0,
    "statement_descriptor": null,
    "subscription": null,
    "subtotal": 20000,
    "tax": null,
    "tax_percent": null,
    "total": 20000,
    "webhooks_delivered_at": 1532039363
  },
  "previous_attributes": null
}`

Answer (score 1):

`$event->data->object->lines->data` is an array. You need to get the first element of the array like `$event->data->object->lines->data[0]` then subscription like `$event->data->object->lines->data[0]->subscription`

Comment: Maybe it's not getting far. Try to var_dump() step by step from ``$event->data`` to  ``$event->data->object->lines->data`` and see where it's getting broken.

Comment: That should work, I tried and it worked for me, if your event object matches what you have in your question. What do you actually get?